# Angular kendo grid refresh

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, refresh, datasource

Scenario:Update the angular kendo grid on click of various buttons.Able to update the grid with new service returned values.

Issue: Angular kendo grid flickers for a second while refreshing.

HTML Structure: Tried with & without k-ng-delay

```
 <div id="alertGrid" kendo-grid k-options="alertGridOptions"
  k-rebind="alertGridOptions"  k-ng-delay="alertGridOptions.dataSource">
 </div>
```

The function that is called on click of refresh buttons

```
    $scope.renderAlertGrid=function(){
          $scope.alertDataSource.read();
          //$('#alertGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
      };
```

Tried to use only refresh, it dint worked out. No impact in using along with read() as well.

Everything is working fine,just that UI becomes little awkward during refresh due to that 1 sec flicker and refresh.

Kindly help out

Thanks

Comment: can you put your code on http://dojo.telerik.com/

Comment: Did you figure out anything more Yoda? My problem is that the scrollbars, column ordering and collapsed grouping reset whenever I update/add/delete an item in the dataSource

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your **data source** is declared inside your **options object** and you're binding to your data by referencing your **options object** using `k-options` and then you are using `k-rebind` to watch for changes on your **options object**. So every time your **data source** changes in your **options object** the entire grid will re-render and all your scroll etc will reset because `k-rebind` re-renders every time a change in your **options object** is detected.

You need to remove `k-rebind` and bind to your **data source** separately using the `k-data-source` attribute. Then the rows in your grid will update when the data changes in your **data source** without re-rendering the entire grid.

`k-rebind` is used when the **options object** has to be changed and the entire widget re-rendered. For example switching a bar chart to a pie chart. That requires a full re-render. `k-rebind` is a bit of a hack and should be avoided imo.